# When is the Force.com IDE going to be rewritten (using the tooling api)

Tags: ide, tooling-api

Last year I attended the Dreamforce session: [Next Generation Debugging with the Developer Console and Tooling API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmQNseA6Gak)

One of the most exciting things that was mentioned was that the Force.com IDE is being rewritten to take advantage of the Tooling API.

Does anyone have any details about when this is happening? I assumed it would have been Spring '13 which was when the Tooling API went GA, but having now read the summer '13 release notes and still seen no mention, I am now wondering when this will happen.

Comment: I didn't have time to view all of the video before posting, but there was an update to the Eclipse plug-in that was released sometime back in Feb as near as I can recall. The Dev Console does support the features they were talking about at the beginning of the video. I suspect though that what you're speaking of "will arrive when we see it".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We are working on this project right now.

The Tooling API was GA in Spring, but it is still not complete, and we've been spending time to make it more robust.  The API can support much of what the IDE plug-in does, but not everything (yet).

Our current plan is to complete the refactor of the IDE plug-in for Spring '14 release.

Comment: This is great news. I'd heard a rumor the IDE would be deprecated in favor of the developer console, but as great as the developer console is for small projects, I can't see it taking over for larger applications.