# Why does Force.com IDE Synchronize view show non-existent differences?

Tags: ide

When I use "Force.com->Synchronize With Server", the synchronize view shows some files as having outbound changes, when no changes exist.  For example:

[image: Syncronize Panel]

Each individual file difference shown here is a file for which no diff exists.  When this happens, the icon is always a grey "outbound change" arrow.  Double clicking to open the file diff shows no diffs of any kind; enabling/disabling the "Ignore White Space" option makes to difference.  Right-clicking and choosing 'Apply Server to Project' pulls a fresh copy of the file, but the file still shows as a diff in synchronize view (even after running a fresh "Synchronize with Server").  Right-clicking and choosing 'Apply Project to Server' will save the file to the server (per the status message), but the again, the file still shows as a diff in synchronize view (even after running a fresh "Synchronize with Server").

These aren't the only email templates/objects/workflows in the org; there are plenty of items that are correctly synced and showing no differences.  But once an item starts showing this behavior, it continues to do so.

I am currently using Force.com IDE v 29.0.0.201310181333 on Eclipse Juno SR2 (build 20130225-0426) on Mac OS X 10.7.5, but I have seen the behavior in other versions; I was using IDE v 28 on Eclipse Indigo previously and had the same issue.  Is this a known issue?  An Eclipse bug?  Anyone have a fix or workaround?

Comment: I know git experiences this issue around line-endings. I wonder if this is similar.

Comment: Edited post to mention I'm on a Mac; line endings is a possibility, but shouldn't save to server and/or refresh from server fix that?  Or if it's happening during save/refresh, wouldn't it affect all files?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that this problem exists and has no solution I'm aware of. I think it is related to timestamp comparisons on the files but that's just a vague memory.

When I want to do a reliable comparison between either what's on my IDE and the server, or what's on two servers, I use the Force.com Migration (Ant) Tool to download the contents of what I'm comparing, then I use a third party comparison tool (WinMerge is my current tool of choice). It's an annoying process compared to good IDE integration, but it works.

Note that Salesforce's position on whether the IDE is officially supported [has flip-flopped a few times](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported), and it has received an embarrassingly low level of attention from SFDC development over the past few years. Things are allegedly getting better, but I'd suggest looking into MavensMate as a viable alternative that you may or may not prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I've have an almost identical setup and see the same problem.  However, I've also seen the problem with older version of Eclipse and Salesforce releases (back to v24 at least).

I've always just ignored them and haven't yet found a good answer as to why.