# Ctrl Click doesn't work in Force.com Ide?

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse, class, code

I get used to ctrl+click code assist which would find the declaration of a variable/class/method in Eclipse, Visual Studio, Borland\Embarcadero Delphi. It is an extremely useful feature when dealing with a large code base.

I have following options enabled 
[image]

as it should be for this Code Assist working in Eclipse, but this doesn't affect Apex Classes?

Am I missing anything or this feature is generally unavailable in Force.com IDE?..

Comment: I use MavensMate Force.com IDE with sublime text editor and works great.http://mavensmate.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything.  It doesn't affect Apex Classes. There is no CTRL + click navigation functionality for Apex Classes in the Force.com IDE.

However, there is work being done, so don't fret too much. :)  Look at [this question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported).

Comment: Hmmm... Then in such case it is very sad that such must-have feature is missing in Force.com IDE.
Let's then create an idea on salesforce success community and vote for it
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1sbAAA

Comment: @Patlatus - Look at [this question and answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported) - It is being refactored to use the tooling API.  I think that many more rich features will then be available. Also, hopefully, it will be open sourced or support some sort of plug in mechanism.

Comment: Anyway that answer doesn't really answer my question. It is still obscure what kind of "tooling API" will be. Doubt it will include this feature

Comment: I agree.  It is definitely unknown, what will be released. (Everything is Safe Harbor, anyway).  If it is open sourced and Eclipse is as well, someone will be able to add that feature in.

Answer (score 0):

Please open apex class with Java Editor. Some of intelisense or ctrl+o functions should work then.