# What's the difference between Force.com IDE 3.7 (Indigo) and 4.3 (Kepler)?

Tags: force.com, ide

A while ago, I tried hard to install eclipse 4.2 (Juno) but didn't succeed.
Now SF mentioned to support Kepler, I tried to install and: It worked!

So far, so good, but what is the big win on this? Old things that are really annoying me are still there, like no inserting of spaces instead of tabs when opening a new {} structure or indenting more than one line at a time, or false-positive sync results on files containing special characters, e.g. umlauts.

Does anybody know or experience noticeable improvements? Or has anybody ideas/solutions for the above mentioned problems I face?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force.com IDE - Still Officially Supported?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the differences between versions of Eclipse.

Comment: The question is about the Force.com IDE with the mention of Eclipse versions just hiding that a little.

Answer (score 4):

The main story is provided in the accepted answer to [Force.com IDE - Still Officially Supported?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported).

The current Force.com IDE has had little effort spent on it over the last several years beyond basic maintenance. That means that rather than new features or even the fixing of annoying bugs, the work has been primarily to support newer versions of the Salesforce platform's APIs and compatibility with Eclipse versions (such as Kepler).

A version that makes use of the newer tooling APIs (that tools like [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) are already taking advantage of) should appear at some point (see [Force.com IDE - any news on the "after the refactor version"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30706/force-com-ide-any-news-on-the-after-the-refactor-version)) but how good that will be remains to be seen.

The most common solution you will see posted on this site to the problems is to move to one of the 3rd party tools.