# Enable Code-Completion in Force.com IDE 2

Tags: apex, force.com-ide, salesforcedx

**How can I activate Code-Completion, and other Language Server features in Force.com IDE 2?** It's not working for me.

I'm fairly new to Salesforce development in general, and don't have broad awareness of toolsets. Currently, I'm getting started with Salesforce DX.

I'm not positive, but my interpretation of docs is that the Apex Language Server is available in beta for Salesforce DX, and I should be able to get code-completion and other features in the Force.com IDE 2.

The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_build_app_apex_language_server_protocol.htm) say "The Apex Language Server isn’t generally available unless or until Salesforce announces its general availability in documentation or in press releases or public statements." However, the same [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm) also say "Salesforce DX isn’t generally available unless or until Salesforce announces its general availability in documentation or in press releases or public statements", in reference to the entire toolset which I'm currently using. That in conjunction with the fact that I see others are using it with VS Code makes me think it's online, and I'm just doing something wrong.

The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_build_app_apex_code_analysis.htm) also say "These features are available in any Salesforce DX project that includes a valid `sfdx-project.json` file that you import into the IDE." I thought perhaps that meant there was something configured in that file, so I downloaded the [sample projects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_samples.htm); but there's nothing different from mine in there.

I verified my local OS allows network access to `forceide`, per [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_build_app_apex_code_analysis.htm).

I have no language servers currently visibly configured in the "Window : Preferences : Language Servers" list. When I select "Add..." in that configuration screen, I see items like "Apex" in content-types on the left, and "Force.com" in Language Server Launch Configuration on the right. They can't be activated though.

Comment: For the moment, I've switched to Visual Studio Code and installed the Salesforce DX plugins for it. Would still like to know what I did wrong in the standard tools (Eclipse / Force.com IDE 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will not add this to Force.com IDE 2.

Instead, we are focusing on the language services for Apex, Visualforce, and Lightning, and our extension for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thank you Wade. I'd like to make sure I understand. When you say "we" you are speaking for the Salesforce DX product team, and you are saying you are focusing on the VS Code IDE extension to support the language services for first three items in your list. That is in lieu of the Eclipse plugins to support those same language services; and therefore while the central "language server" is shared, effectively your team's development of the Force.com IDE 2 is halted or suspended. Did I understand that correctly? In summary, I should probably use VSCode.

Comment: Wade, in case you interpreted my comment as snarky, it was not meant to be. I really had wanted to make sure I understood. I was confused because language services would also support other IDEs, like eclipse, so I wasn't certain I read your answer correctly. Also, because this link (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_get_started.htm) still is around.

Comment: Wade's like a Honey Badger, he don't care ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, @shannon! I completely missed the comment (no notifications). We will keep the existing Force.com IDE in OSS (and likely fix any major issues) but we will no longer invest in the Force.com IDE 2. Yes, consider using VS Code with our extensions. Alternatively, Illuminated Cloud and The Welkins Suite are great tools to consider.